# Why there is no output from whereis -s?

Tags: bash

I am traying to find the source-code-file of the bash package.

~ $ whereis bash
bash: /bin/bash /etc/bash.bashrc /usr/share/man/man1/bash.1.gz

~ $ whereis -s bash

bash:

Why there is no output from the whereis -s bash? In the man page of whereis it is said that the -s option makes whereis to 'Search only for sources.' But there is no output from whereis -s bash. Why? What should I check?

Comment: Why are you expecting to find source for bash on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is obvious: there is no source for `bash` in Ubuntu.

You can download source for `bash` by

```
apt source bash
```

You will need to enable sources in "Software & Updates" to get it working.

Comment: I was thinking ubuntu was open source. Shouldn't there be a source for bash?

Comment: Ubuntu is open-source. But that doesn't mean all sources are inside the system.

Comment: @ Pilot6: But they should be available. Inside or outside the system.

Comment: They are available ;-)

Comment: apt source bash
Reading package lists... Done
E: You must put some 'source' URIs in your sources.list

Comment: Enable package sources for `main` first.